# Problems with expo cli using the IOS simulator

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo, ios-simulator

I'm new to using react native and I'm having some problems getting the IOS simulator to work.
I created the react project with:

```
expo init appName
```

And then cd into the folder and started the app with:

```
expo start
```

I then chose to run on IOS simulator. The simulator loads but when I open the Expo Go app the app doesn't work and I see the following error:

[image: screenshot of IOS simulator]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I've already tried to create a diferent react project, use a diferent simulator, restarting the app and uninstaling it.

(btw, i'm using a mac on macos Big Sur)

Answer (score 0):

you can try `yarn ios`

or maybe change the connection in `http://localhost:19000/` to tunnel.

could you share a screenshot from `http://localhost:19000/`?

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer, try using the comment section to ask a question, thanks

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.